# Show Map View Annotation in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UItableview Cell with a MKMapView and a couple UIButtons, I have set the cell to `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` As I only want the map to be tapped or the buttons, and I am trying to display the MapPin Annotation either programitcally or when the user taps it. Here is what I have tried

```
cell.mapView.delegate = self;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0} };
    region.center.latitude = 0;
    region.center.longitude = 0;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [cell.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    MapPin *ann = [[MapPin alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"title";
    ann.subtitle = @"subtitle";
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    [cell.mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    [cell.mapView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
```

The above code is called in cellForRowAtIndexPath and I tried to do ti programatically with this line `[cell.mapView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];` but the pin appears but there is not text above it with `@"title"`?

How can I show the title?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you created custom Class for your cell ?

Comment: @PankajTeckchandani yes I have

Comment: Can you please post your MapPin class and Tableview delegate methods code. Coz your code is working fine for me.

Comment: @PankajTeckchandani here it is https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4f04c3c1e1ab37a4a02c

Comment: if possible plesea share the storyboard as well

Comment: @PankajTeckchandani you want an image of it? I have added an image to the question

Comment: yeah fine. That would be enough

Comment: @PankajTeckchandani thanks for reply but I solved it, I just had a typo

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TableViewCell *riCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"riCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    riCell.mapView.delegate = self;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0,0.0}, {0.0,0.0} };
    region.center.latitude = 0;
    region.center.longitude = 0;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [riCell.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    MapPin *ann = [[MapPin alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"title";
    ann.subtitle = @"subject";
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    [riCell.mapView addAnnotation:ann];
    [riCell.mapView selectAnnotation:ann animated:YES];
    return riCell;
 }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return 2;//You can replace this with number of rows you want
}
```